# Social Pluggin Comment Box used in Facebook Developers

Tags: facebook, comments

Using a Facebook comment box social pluggin. Our site is currently in the beginning process of converting to an HTML5. But, noticed with the Facebook comment boxes there is no option for pre-HTML5 codes. In the Implementation pull down it only has HTML5 or xfbml - Why not have a pre-HTML5 option as well?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 output by the Facebook plugins is also valid pre-HTML5. It's just a `<script>` tag and a `<div>` tag.